# Maximum call stack size exceeded vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router

I am facing this problem when i try to redirect the user to their path depends on their roles_id value

```js
const getUserRole = (to, from, next) => {
  const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
  if (currentUser) {
    if (currentUser.roles_id === 1 && to.name === "user-dashboard") {
      next({
        name: "dashboard-new"
      });
    } else if (currentUser.roles_id === 2 && to.name === "dashboard-new") {
      next({
        name: "user-dashboard"
      });
    } else if (currentUser.roles_id === 3 && to.name === "mails-track") {
      next({
        name: "dispatch-dashboard"
      });
    } else if (to.name === "dashboard-new" && currentUser.roles_id === 1) {
      next();
    } else if (to.name === "user-dashboard" && currentUser.roles_id === 2) {
      next();
    } else if (to.name === "dispatch-dashboard" && currentUser.roles_id === 3) {
      next();
    } else {
      next("/");
    }
  } else {
    next("/");
  }
};

export default [{
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "dashboard-new",
    component: () =>
      import ("@/views/dashboard/new/DashboardNew.vue"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    },
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
      if (currentUser && currentUser.roles_id === 1) {
        getUserRole(to, from, next);
      } else {
        next("/");
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/user-dashboard",
    name: "user-dashboard",
    component: () =>
      import ("@/views/dashboard/new/user/UserDashboard.vue"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    },
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
      if (currentUser && currentUser.roles_id === 2) {
        getUserRole(to, from, next);
      } else {
        next("/");
      }
    }
  }
];
```

But I am getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" i tried to use switch condition and also didn't work

It is working fine on local but once i upload it to my host it show this problem

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: It's unknown what's the setup on remote host and how it differs. You didn't post the actual error, currently only you can process and debug it. Considering that the router causes it, just place the breakpoint at each `next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a debugging i found that in local `currentUser.roles_id === 1` will return 1 as number but in host will return it as string

so in this case i don't need to specify the type in '===' so i changed it to '==' to check only the value